# How to get AX1650 working on Debian Linux?

Tags: debian, wifi-driver

As described by Intel, this particular wireless card needs some hacking, because Debian installer does not contain the necessary firmware:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058910/wireless/intel-wireless-products.html

However, following their instructions did not solve the problem. I've tried this one too, without success:
https://m7c1.com/posts/install-killer-ax1650-drivers-and-get-wifi-with-only-a-usb-and-a-debian-netinstaller

From the kernel log file it seems that something's fishy with the firmware version

```
[    1.750300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[    1.750523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode (-2)
[    1.750565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750573] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-54.ucode (-2)
[    1.750610] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750616] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode (-2)
[    1.750651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-52.ucode (-2)
[    1.750690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-51.ucode (-2)
[    1.750726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode (-2)
[    1.750762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.750765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-49.ucode (-2)
[    1.750794] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode (-2)
[    1.751196] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751201] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-47.ucode (-2)
[    1.751225] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-46.ucode (-2)
[    1.751260] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751265] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-45.ucode (-2)
[    1.751293] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751297] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-44.ucode (-2)
[    1.751320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode (-2)
[    1.751346] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751350] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-42.ucode (-2)
[    1.751373] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751377] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-41.ucode (-2)
[    1.751400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751404] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-40.ucode (-2)
[    1.751429] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751433] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-39.ucode (-2)
[    1.751457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    1.751458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    1.751482] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-39
[    1.751508] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-55
```

Any idea how to get this working? I have kernel version 4.19.0-17-amd64, but also tried upgrading to linux-image-amd64 (5.10.46-2~bpo10+1).

EDIT:
SOLVED! I've upgraded kernel to 5.10.x and installed the iwlwifi firmware from bullseye_di_rc3/, and it works! Thank you so much for helping!

What I don't get is why don't they just include the latest kernel into the installer...

EDIT2:
The connection is very unstable though. It oftentimes disconnects and fails to reconnect with error "Authentication request to the driver failed". I know it's not the AP's fault, I have other devices connected to the same network, they run flawlessly.

Comment: try this one: https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/firmware-iwlwifi

Comment: I've tried it already, no effect.

Comment: It might not work in the end, but as it contains the microcode not found in your question, lack of firmware would not be the cause of failure anymore. Do the kernel logs change then? ie: no more `no suitable firmware found!`. What happens then?

Comment: I'll check and let you know, thanks! In the meantime I've booted a live ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.8.0-43-generic -- with this one, it works without problems.

Comment: Of course when you try again you must use the 5.10.x backport kernel along this firmware

Comment: You must not "solve" the question in the question. You could consider @bk2204's answer which wasn't that far, or write your own answer stating what you did (but using buster-backports should have been the same rather than do something strange that can't be upgraded (well until next weeks when bullseye is out).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is to install the kernel and the `firmware-iwlwifi` package from bullseye.  The kernel contains support for this chip, and the firmware appears to be properly packaged (although I don't have that chip, so I can't verify).

If you're trying to install for the first time, you can either install without the firmware from the buster or bullseye official images by using a wired connection and then install the appropriate packages, or you can try the [unofficial bullseye images that support firmware](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/bullseye/), which should let you install using a Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: Will try, thank you!